# Sequelize Joins not returning required results

Tags: sequelize.js

Trying to work out how to correctly setup Joins using Sequelize, probably doe snot help that I am not very familiar with SQL as a whole.

```
models.farms.hasMany(models.users, {foreignKey: 'farmId'});
models.users.belongsTo(models.farms, {foreignKey: 'farmId'});

models.users.find({
    where: {id:33},
    include: [models.farms]
})
.then(function(aResponse) {
    aNext(null, aResponse);
})
.catch(function(aError) {
    aNext(aError);
});
```

The users table had a field of 'farmId', and the farms table has the same field, and I am trying to match them up using that as I need specific ID's for the farms later on. If I update users to math 'id' then it works, but not 'farmId' which is how I need it.

farms also will have other joins going out to farm_area and crop_types, possible more later, still working out all the logic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your associations in the definition of your model, like

```
sequelize.define('users', {
  id: DataTypes.Integer,
  farmId: DataTypes.Integer
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      users.belongsTo(models.farms, {
        foreignKey: 'farmId'
      });
  }
}
```

It worked for me when trying to use custom foreign keys names.